# Animate image js

Tags: javascript

I have 2 images on canvas and i want to make imageObg to animate. Actually i want it to make a linear move to the right.I found a way to animate an object like a rectangle but i cant animate an image object that i use from another source.

Is there anyway that can i manage to do i? Does anyone knows?

```js
 window.onload = function() {

   var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   var imageObj = new Image();
   var imageObj2 = new Image();

   imageObj.onload = function() {
     context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 130);
   };

   imageObj2.onload = function() {
     context.drawImage(imageObj2, 0, 0);
   };


   imageObj.src = 'http://imageshack.com/a/img745/822/pXDK5F.png'
   imageObj2.src = 'http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/09/04/1409790551890_wps_28_Astronaut_Reid_Wiseman_po.jpg'

 };
```

```css
 body {
   background-color: black
 }
```

```html
<div id='d1' style="position:absolute; top:80px; left:150px; z-index:1">
  <canvas id='myCanvas' width='962' height='500' style="border:10px solid #ffffff;">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just two things.

1. Set a periodically render routine using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval).
2. Set a move (or physics) routine, call it after each render.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = new Image();
  var imageObj2 = new Image();

  imageObj.src = 'http://imageshack.com/a/img745/822/pXDK5F.png'
  imageObj2.src = 'http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/09/04/1409790551890_wps_28_Astronaut_Reid_Wiseman_po.jpg'

  window.setInterval(renderFrame, 50);

  var ship = {
    x: 69,
    y: 130
  };

  function renderFrame() {

    moveShip();

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (imageObj.complete) {
      context.drawImage(imageObj2, 0, 0);
    }
    if (imageObj.complete) {
      context.drawImage(imageObj, ship.x, ship.y);
    }
  }

  function moveShip() {
    ship.x += 20;
    if (ship.x > canvas.width) {
      ship.x = 0 - imageObj.width;
      ship.y = Math.random() * 250 + 50;
    }

  }

};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<div id='d1' style="position:absolute; top:80px; left:150px; z-index:1">
  <canvas id='myCanvas' width='962' height='500' style="border:10px solid #ffffff;">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man this works great. Do you know how can i stop imageObj moving after e.g one moving circle? (i am newbie in js :D)

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the x position of the image with a `setInterval` command.

```
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
var img.src = [Image Source];

var x = 0;
window.setInterval(function() {
  x ++;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.drawImage(img, x, 0);
}, 50);
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

Here is a [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7n1hgxd5/).